# Get only matching rows for groups in Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following df:

```
d = {"Col1":['a','d','b','c','a','d','b','c'],
"Col2":['x','y','x','z','x','y','z','y'],
"Col3":['n','m','m','l','m','m','l','l'],
"Col4":[1,4,2,2,1,4,2,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

When I groupby on three fields, I get the result:

```
gb = df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])['Col4'].agg(['sum', 'mean'])
```

[image]

How can I extract only the groups and rows where a row of a group matches with at least one other row of another group on grouped columns. Please see the picture below, I want to get the highlighted rows

[image]

I want to get the rows in red on the basis of the ones in Blue and Black which match eachother

Apologies if my statement is ambiguous. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `reset_index` then use `duplicated` and boolean index filter your dataframe:

```
gb = gb.reset_index()
gb[gb.duplicated(subset=['Col2','Col3'], keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3  sum  mean
0    a    x    m    1     1
2    b    x    m    2     2
3    b    z    l    2     2
5    c    z    l    2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a table with all allowed combinations and then inner join it with this dataframe.